How to move a vertex of an animated mesh in world space instead of local space?
I'm trying to add a vector to the selected objects vertex.
def force(self):
        gravity = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, -0.5))
        
        obj = bpy.context.object
        
        obj.data.vertices[0].co += gravity

problem visualized

The mesh is in it's rest position.
The force() method is executed.
The mesh is deformed by an armature modifier.
The force() method is executed.

As you can see, the translation of the vertex is still applied in the objects local space.
The solution I've tried is to use the objects "matrix_world". This doesn't work as I then get the the identity matrix of the objects transformation, which doesn't change at all since I'm transforming vertices, not the object.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I found the solution!
gravity = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, -0.3))
    
    obj = bpy.context.object
    
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
    
    obj.crazyspace_eval(depsgraph, scene)
    
    delta = obj.crazyspace_displacement_to_original(vertex_index=0, displacement=gravity)
    
    obj.data.vertices[0].co += delta

    obj.crazyspace_eval_clear()

Running the "crazyspace_eval()" method on my object, and then adding the result of "crazyspace_displacement_to_original()" to the coordinates of my vertex solved the issue.
Solution visualized
: https://i.sstatic.net/82GgxmAT.jpg
As shown in this picture, the "gravity" vector added to the object before(1) and after(2) it has been deformed by an armature modifier.
